# Error while connecting to Salesforce using ADF - ERROR: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to access salesforce through Azure Data Factory by creating linked service and I'm seeing error as: ERROR [HYOOO] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (148) INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.

Steps followed:

- Added Copy data in a pipeline
- Selected Salesforce as new data set in copy data as source
- Integration Runtime, tested with both Azure's AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime and Self hosted Integration Runtime but no luck
- Environment URL as https://something.salesforce.com
- username as **something@something.com**, password and security token.
- API version is kept as **Default**

**NOTE:** I am able to login to salesforce successfully through browser using custom login/company login and authentication is passed **via Microsoft login page**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by resetting password and security token, not sure how that worked because while doing trial and error in ADF I had logged simultaneously to Salesforce through web browser and I was able import tables from Power BI with ease. Although now the problem is solved I'm good with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the salesforce URL is in a public network or it is in your organization network. If the salesforce is in your organization's network, then you may need to install SHIR in a computer in your company's network and then try creating a linked service with that SHIR to connect to the salesforce.

Comment: Hey @mba026, the URL is a public network.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, I did try with both the URL's, one was the universal link i.e https://login.salesforce.com and other one was custom to our Organization which is https://something.salesforce.com but no luck.